# Keep looping until no further changes to list

Tags: python, list, loops

Example:

```
# Input
n = 5

List :    [34 56 20 90 100]
Round 1 : [34 36 20 90 100]
Round 2 : [34 16 20 90 100]
Round 3 : [18 16 20 90 100]
Round 4 : [2  16 20 90 100]

# Output
No. of rounds : 4
```

If the first number is greater than the second then they are subtracted and this new number replaces the first num. But if the first number is less than the second number, the first number is unchanged. Here `v` take the input `n` from the user and this `n` is the length of the list. Whatever the list of nums is, the last number remains same.

Here is the code I have written to obtain the initial list from user input:

```
import random

l1 = []
n = int(input('enter a num: '))

for i in range(n):
    a = random.randint(1, 100)
    l1.append(a)

print(l1)
b = l1.pop()
```

Comment: Just to confirm - So you will like to get the *count* of how many rounds needed to transform the original to the desired ascending list?

Comment: yes, the number of rounds till the last list obtained is the same as the  previous list

Comment: Try something like this - start with a while-loop (checking if the array is in total ascending order): inside this loop, just iterate previous with current number and do necessary operation. (Using zip)

Answer (score 1):

This applies some function `f` to `x` until it is told to stop:

```
def accumulate_until(x, f):
    """Yields results of each iteration until told to stop."""
    while True:
        yield x
        x, stop = f(x)
        if stop:
            return
```

An alternative to `yield x` is to save the results into a list using `xs.append(x)`, and then to return that list once done:

```
def accumulate_until(x, f):
    """Yields results of each iteration until told to stop."""
    xs = []
    while True:
        xs.append(x)
        x, stop = f(x)
        if stop:
            return xs
```

For your specific problem, one can craft a function "`f`", which we will call "`run_iteration`", as follows:

```
def find_index(xs):
    """Find index of first element which violates monotonicity."""
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(xs, xs[1:])):
        if x > y:
            return i
    return None

def run_iteration(xs):
    """Repairs the first number which violates monotonicity."""
    xs = list(xs)
    i = find_index(xs)
    if i is None:
        return xs, True
    xs[i] = xs[i] - xs[i + 1]
    return xs, False
```

Now, one simply needs to plug in `run_iteration` into `accumulate_until`:

```
xs = [34, 56, 20, 90, 100]
rounds = list(accumulate_until(xs, run_iteration))
```

Printing out the results in a human-readable manner:

```
for i, data in enumerate(rounds):
    print(f"Round {i}: {data}")

print(f"\nTotal rounds: {len(rounds)}")
```

---

Complete example:

```
def find_index(xs):
    """Find index of first element which violates monotonicity."""
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(xs, xs[1:])):
        if x > y:
            return i
    return None

def run_iteration(xs):
    """Repairs the first number which violates monotonicity."""
    xs = list(xs)
    i = find_index(xs)
    if i is None:
        return xs, True
    xs[i] = xs[i] - xs[i + 1]
    return xs, False

def accumulate_until(x, f):
    """Yields results of each iteration until told to stop."""
    while True:
        yield x
        x, stop = f(x)
        if stop:
            return

xs = [34, 56, 20, 90, 100]
rounds = list(accumulate_until(xs, run_iteration))

for i, data in enumerate(rounds):
    print(f"Round {i}: {data}")

print(f"\nTotal rounds: {len(rounds)}")
```

Output:

```
Round 0: [34, 56, 20, 90, 100]
Round 1: [34, 36, 20, 90, 100]
Round 2: [34, 16, 20, 90, 100]
Round 3: [18, 16, 20, 90, 100]
Round 4: [2, 16, 20, 90, 100]

Total rounds: 5
```